# tkPDFViewer - Open several .pdf in grid not working (display same pdf with a mix of all of them)

Tags: python, tkinter, tkpdfviewer

My goal is to display several PDFs at the same time in `tkinter`.

My issue is that it seems not possible to open different .pdf at the same time using : `tkPDFViewer`

The reproducible example is below :

```
    from tkPDFViewer import tkPDFViewer as pdf

    FramePdfMacro = tk.Frame(self,bg='white')
    FramePdfMacro.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH,pady=2,padx=2)
    
    FramePdfMacro.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    Grid.rowconfigure(FramePdfMacro, 0, weight=1)
    Grid.columnconfigure(FramePdfMacro, 0, weight=1)
    Grid.columnconfigure(FramePdfMacro, 1, weight=1)
    
    PDF1 = pdf.ShowPdf()
    PDFv1 = PDF1.pdf_view(FramePdfMacro, pdf_location = "PDF1.pdf",width = 100, height = 150)
    PDFv1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nsew")    
    
    PDF2 = pdf.ShowPdf()
    PDFv2 = PDF2.pdf_view(FramePdfMacro, pdf_location = "PDF2.pdf",width = 100,height = 150)
    PDFv2.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="nsew")
```

Once you run this code you will get twice a mix of those 2 .pdf

Does anyone knows how to display 2 differents `.pdf` in a same time ?

Comment: For current design of `tkPDFViewer`, the answer is NO.

Comment: @acw1668 do you know an other way  to do it so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For current design of `tkPDFViewer`, you cannot show two PDF files at the same time.

Since `tkPDFViewer` use `pyMuPDF` module, you can create your PDF viewer using same module as below:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
import fitz

class PDFViewer(ScrolledText):
    def show(self, pdf_file):
        self.delete('1.0', 'end') # clear current content
        pdf = fitz.open(pdf_file) # open the PDF file
        self.images = []   # for storing the page images
        for page in pdf:
            pix = page.get_pixmap()
            pix1 = fitz.Pixmap(pix, 0) if pix.alpha else pix
            photo = tk.PhotoImage(data=pix1.tobytes('ppm'))
            # insert into the text box
            self.image_create('end', image=photo)
            self.insert('end', '\n')
            # save the image to avoid garbage collected
            self.images.append(photo)

root = tk.Tk()
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure((0,1), weight=1)

pdf1 = PDFViewer(root, width=80, height=30, spacing3=5, bg='blue')
pdf1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
pdf1.show('test.pdf')

pdf2 = PDFViewer(root, width=80, height=30, spacing3=5, bg='blue')
pdf2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')
pdf2.show('temp.pdf')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Looking your answer thank you, will give you feedback soon

Comment: Working so nicely thank you

Comment: Do you know a way to allow user to zoom PDF ?

Comment: Or to load the pdf a bit bigger in order to make it more readable

Comment: @TourEiffel See official document on ["How to Increase Image Resolution"](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-to-increase-image-resolution) of `PyMuPDF`.